# How can I limit the Length of b-bone (Bendy Bone)

Tags: bones

After I made a Bendy Bone. I can drag my handle very far.
How can I limit the Length of b-bone (Bendy Bone).
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

OK! I got it.
Just use "blender limit distance constraint".
Thank you.